# Does Sorceress bless carryover between game reset?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

If I get a blessing from the Sorceress, exit the game, start the game again and enter the dungeon, will I still have the blessing?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The Priestess' (not Sorceress) Blessing only lasts for one run.

Comment: This is still a little unclear to me. OP asks if the blessing will last if he receives it, closes then game, opens the game, and *then* starts a run. I.e., does closing the game before actually starting a run remove the blessing from the upcoming run?